# Javascript/Json show key value list based on key value inside property

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to be able to pull a list of key values based on a value present inside properties.

My code so far.

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObjjj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var e;
        var q;
        var w = "";

        for (q in myObjjj.features[0].properties.AREAID) {
            w += myObjjj.features[q].properties.CDNAME + "<br>";
        }

        document.getElementById("demog").innerHTML = w;
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.npoint.io/d901ff317ae962d8c376", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Read data from External JSON file using JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>
        Data extracted from External JSON file using JavaScript.
    </h3>
    
    <p id="demog" style="border: 2px solid blue;"></p>      
</body>
</html>
```

Json from URL - https://api.npoint.io/d901ff317ae962d8c376

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4811","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 11","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4807","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 7","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4815","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 15","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4802","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 2","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4808","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 8","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4803","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 3","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4801","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 1","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4804","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 4","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4801","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 1","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4804","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 4","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4806","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 6","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4816","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 16","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4812","COLOR":"#0600ff","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area5","CDNAME":"Division No. 12","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4805","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 5","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4817","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 17","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4813","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 13","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4810","COLOR":"#0600ff","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area5","CDNAME":"Division No. 10","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4819","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 19","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4818","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 18","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4814","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 14","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4809","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 9","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}}]}
```

I am assuming it needs some version of

For each `myObjjj.features[i].properties.AREAID` pull all `myObjjj.features[q].properties.CDNAME`

The desired result:

**area4**

Division No. 11

Division No. 16

Division No. 17

Division No. 13

Division No. 19

Division No. 18

Division No. 14

Not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this wanted result? `AREAID = area4` get that objects  `CDNAME`?

You can simply filter object by `AREAID`:

```
.filter(c => c.properties.AREAID === "area4")
```

then map only its `CDNAME`

```
.map(res => res.properties.CDNAME+"<br>")
```

Whole code that gives wanted result in one line:

```
var result = myObjjj.features.filter(c => c.properties.AREAID === "area4").map(res => res.properties.CDNAME+"<br>").join('');
```

`join.(" ")` at end is to join the results in array so you dont get comas of array when printing in document.

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {



  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObjjj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    var result = myObjjj.features.filter(c => c.properties.AREAID === "area4").map(res => res.properties.CDNAME + "<br>").join('');
    document.getElementById("demog").innerHTML = result;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.npoint.io/d901ff317ae962d8c376", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Read data from External JSON file using JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>
    Data extracted from External JSON file using JavaScript.
  </h3>

  <p id="demog" style="border: 2px solid blue;"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this reduce?

If you want to not have dupes in for example area3, we can use a Set

```js
const data = { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4811", "COLOR": "#ff00f0", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area4", "CDNAME": "Division No. 11", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4807", "COLOR": "#00fffc", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area1", "CDNAME": "Division No. 7", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4815", "COLOR": "#fffc00", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area2", "CDNAME": "Division No. 15", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4802", "COLOR": "#ff0000", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area3", "CDNAME": "Division No. 2", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4808", "COLOR": "#00fffc", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area1", "CDNAME": "Division No. 8", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4803", "COLOR": "#fffc00", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area2", "CDNAME": "Division No. 3", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4801", "COLOR": "#ff0000", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area3", "CDNAME": "Division No. 1", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4804", "COLOR": "#ff0000", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area3", "CDNAME": "Division No. 4", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4801", "COLOR": "#ff0000", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area3", "CDNAME": "Division No. 1", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4804", "COLOR": "#ff0000", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area3", "CDNAME": "Division No. 4", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4806", "COLOR": "#fffc00", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area2", "CDNAME": "Division No. 6", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4816", "COLOR": "#ff00f0", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area4", "CDNAME": "Division No. 16", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4812", "COLOR": "#0600ff", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area5", "CDNAME": "Division No. 12", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4805", "COLOR": "#fffc00", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area2", "CDNAME": "Division No. 5", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4817", "COLOR": "#ff00f0", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area4", "CDNAME": "Division No. 17", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4813", "COLOR": "#ff00f0", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area4", "CDNAME": "Division No. 13", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4810", "COLOR": "#0600ff", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area5", "CDNAME": "Division No. 10", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4819", "COLOR": "#ff00f0", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area4", "CDNAME": "Division No. 19", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4818", "COLOR": "#ff00f0", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area4", "CDNAME": "Division No. 18", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4814", "COLOR": "#ff00f0", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area4", "CDNAME": "Division No. 14", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CDUID": "4809", "COLOR": "#00fffc", "PRUID": "48", "AREAID": "area1", "CDNAME": "Division No. 9", "CDTYPE": "CDR", "PRNAME": "Alberta", "KML_STYLE": "area6" } } ] }

const extract = data.features.reduce((acc,{properties}) => {
  const { AREAID, CDNAME } = properties;
  acc[AREAID] = acc[AREAID] || []; 
  acc[AREAID].push(CDNAME);
  return acc;
},{});
console.log(extract)
```

Here is a definition list

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    process(JSON.parse(this.responseText));

  }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.npoint.io/d901ff317ae962d8c376", true);
xmlhttp.send();

const process = data => {
  const obj = data.features.reduce((acc, { properties }) => {
    const { AREAID, CDNAME } = properties;
    acc[AREAID] = acc[AREAID] || [];
    acc[AREAID].push(CDNAME);
    return acc;
  }, {});
  document.getElementById("demog").innerHTML = Object
    .entries(obj)
    .map(([key, value]) => `<dt>${key}</dt>${value
      .map(val => `<dd>${val}</dd>`).join("")}`)
    .join("")

}
```

```html
<dl id="demog"></dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question--and I'm not 100% sure I do--you could use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to bin all of the `CDNAME` values by `AREAID`:

```js
const data = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4811","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 11","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4807","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 7","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4815","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 15","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4802","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 2","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4808","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 8","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4803","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 3","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4801","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 1","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4804","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 4","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4801","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 1","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4804","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 4","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4806","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 6","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4816","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 16","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4812","COLOR":"#0600ff","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area5","CDNAME":"Division No. 12","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4805","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 5","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4817","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 17","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4813","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 13","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4810","COLOR":"#0600ff","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area5","CDNAME":"Division No. 10","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4819","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 19","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4818","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 18","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4814","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 14","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4809","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 9","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}}]}

// iterate over the items in data.features
const cdNameByArea = data.features.reduce((acc, item) => {
  // get the values we're interested in from the current item's properties
  const {AREAID, CDNAME} = item.properties;
  
  // add the name to the corresponding area's bin,
  // creating the bin if it doesn't already exist
  acc[AREAID] = [...acc[AREAID] || [], CDNAME]; 
  
  return acc; // return the updated accumulator object for the next iteration
}, {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(cdNameByArea, null, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the JSON provided is assigned to a `response`, you could produce the result:

```
{
  area4: [
    'Division No. 11',
    'Division No. 16',
    'Division No. 17',
    'Division No. 13',
    'Division No. 19',
    'Division No. 18',
    'Division No. 14'
  ],
  area1: [ 'Division No. 7', 'Division No. 8', 'Division No. 9' ],
  area2: [
    'Division No. 15',
    'Division No. 3',
    'Division No. 6',
    'Division No. 5'
  ],
  area3: [
    'Division No. 2',
    'Division No. 1',
    'Division No. 4',
    'Division No. 1',
    'Division No. 4'
  ],
  area5: [ 'Division No. 12', 'Division No. 10' ]
}
```

By first creating an array of unique areas.

```
let { features } = response;

// Find unique area ids
const areaIds = features.reduce((ids, { properties }) => {
  let { AREAID } = properties;

  if (!ids.includes(AREAID)) {
    ids.push(AREAID);
  }

  return ids;
}, []);
```

And then create a list of divisions for each area id.

```
// Create an array of divisions for each area id
const divisions = areaIds.reduce((res, id) => {
  res[id] = features
    .filter(({ properties }) => properties.AREAID == id)
    .map(({ properties }) => properties.CDNAME);

  return res;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let devisions = [];
for (let i = 0; i < YourJSON.features.length;i++) {
  if (YourJSON.features[i].properties.AREAID == "area4") {
    devisions.push(YourJSON.features[i].properties.CDNAME);
  }
}
devisions;

// ["Division No. 11", "Division No. 16", "Division No. 17", "Division No. 13", "Division No. 19", "Division No. 18", "Division No. 14"]
```